# Need to count records with specific condition in FOXPRO

Tags: count, foxpro

I have a FOXPRO table with a non-Unique Name Field, I'd like to query the following;

For each Name Value ("John") count how many records there are (32 records with name John)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY name
```

The query selects all unique values from '*name*' field, and count occurrences of every selected value. The `GROUP BY` is an obligatory clause. It makes selected values distinct. Replace '*table1*' DBF file name with your table's file name.

Comment: Please clarify your answer and explain _why_ this is the answer and what you are doing a bit more, rather than just handing the answer and not making the asker any wiser :)

Comment: Thank you so much... for great help

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on your specs - if you'd have some test data like:

```
CREATE CURSOR test (id Int, FirstName Char(30) Null)
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (1, "John")
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (2, "Adam")
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (3, "John F.")
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (4, "Brian John")
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (5, "Brian John David")
INSERT INTO test (id, FirstName) VALUES (6, "Johnson")
```

... and assumed you want to have an exact match, then in Vfp SQL you could use the `Like` operator (or exactly-equal "=="):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName Like 'John' && count is 1
```

... whereas the standard-SQL "=" operator would depend on Set Ansi in VFP:

```
SET ANSI OFF && default
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName = 'John' && result is 3
SET ANSI ON
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName = 'John' && result is 1
```

In VFP, the standard-SQL '%' placeholder behaves as you might expect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName Like 'John%' && 3
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName Like 'John %' && 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE FirstName Like '%John%' && 5
```

... where the last one would not be optimizable with "native" Vfp DBF tables because VFP itself has no full-text index feature

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers seem to be pure FoxPro code. While using a select query will certainly work, I find it's generally overkill for this type of task.

```
SELECT TABLE
COUNT TO {variable} FOR {CONDITION}
```

For example :

```
COUNT TO lnCount FOR "John" $ NAME
```

Or if you are worried that the case may be different in the table :

```
COUNT TO lnCount FOR "JOHN" $ UPPER(NAME)
```

Comment: He wants the result for *each* unique value in the table, and your suggestion only covers one specific value, which he may not even know. He needs a full list of each unique value, and total of each So, the Select with Count(*) is a more generic solutions and gives all the unique results along with the count of each one.

Comment: Ah, I see from the answer he commented on that he was looking for the counts of each unique version of a given search (for example "John") and return : John Smith x2, John James x2 -- though I don't see that clear in the question asked, and still feel this answers the question asked. If you think I should delete the answer, let me know and I will happily do so.

Answer (score 0):

I like Oleg's answer, and I agree. If you need to run and count the name 'John' in an indexed column, you might need to setup ANSI_NULLS ON..

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

..This helps especially on TRANSACT-SQL.. and by the way, if you want to check if ANSI_NULLS is set to ON, run the here under code.

```
DECLARE @ANSI_NULLS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF'; 
IF ( (32 & @@OPTIONS) = 32 ) SET @ANSI_NULLS = 'ON'; 
SELECT @ANSI_NULLS AS ANSI_NULLS;
```

For more detail information..visit:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx